# Using Sprit-sheet on WordPress categories

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, css

I have added some custom category taxonomy and it's having a field to add icon by the user. i am able display all the categories with icon in the front-end.. but as a part of website optimization if i check with gt matrix it tells to create a sprite-sheet for the icons.

if it was done with html and css i could have done it easily. Each icon is loaded via it's own url.How do i get rid of this issue in WordPress.

thanks

Comment: I don't see how this is any different in WordPress? You'd just need to change how you load your icons. Unless you didn't set that up yourself to begin with? If you didn't then you'd need to check with whoever did it originally.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Hello, actually creating a theme myself.whether u are saying me to allow user to upload sprite-sheet instead of icons?